# Finding translation/rotation parameters from correspondences with Kinect and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, rotation, translation, kinect, correspondence

Say I have an object, and I obtained RGB data and Depth data from a kinect on one angle. Then I moved the kinect slightly so that I can take a second picture of the object from a different angle. I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine how much the kinect camera has translated and rotated from its original position based on the correspondences from both images.

I'm using OpenCV for certain image processing tasks and I've looked into the SURF algorithm, which seems to find good correspondences from two 2D images. However it doesn't take into account the depth data, and I don't think it works very nice with multiple pictures. Additionally, I can't figure out how you can obtain the translation/rotation data from the correspondence.. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong direction?

Note: My long-term goal is to "merge" the multiple images to form a 3D model from all the data. At the moment it somewhat works if I specify the angles that the kinect is located at, but I think it's much better to reduce the "errors" involved (i.e. points shifted slightly from where they should be) by finding correspondences instead of specifying parameters manually

Comment: there is some work already done in this subject, see here: http://manctl.com/products.html

Comment: Eran: I realize this has been done before, but I'm trying to understand the algorithms behind it all so that I can implement it myself. I was hoping that program was opensource but it doesn't look like it. And besides, I'm only planning to scan an object like a bag or something, and not an entire room like the screenshot on that link implies

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16000303/1275880